# Search value in a two-dimensional, non-ordered array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a 2-dimensional array of data, say in a range A1:Z30. This data is not-ordered and hence has no row- or column headers.

I want to find out whether a specific element is given in this table. Note that I do not need to know the position, knowing whether it exists or not is sufficient.

I tried a simple MATCH, but curiously MATCH seemed to work only with a one-dimensional range. Having googled my problem, I only found links to the classical INDEX/MATCH-approach, which assumes that there are row- and column-headers which - as mentioned - I don't have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
=countif(a1:z30, "<my value to look for>")
```

Comment: Thanks, super simple, I just didn't think of it